# VBA Coverting negative decimal numbers to octo and hexa

Tags: vba

i 'm trying to make this program to not only convert positive numbers, but also negative ones. Based on this code, what can I modify so it also convert negative decimal numbers to octo? Also, what can I do if I also want to it convert non-rounded numbers into binary? For example 321.123 to binary.

```
Private Sub Conversion_Click()
Dim chiffreentrer As Integer
Dim reste As Integer
Dim reste2 As String
Dim chiffreocto As String

chiffreentrer = CInt(InputBox("Entrez un chiffre decimal:", "Conversion    Decimal a Octo"))
Do While chiffreentrer >= 1
    reste = chiffreentrer Mod 8
    reste2 = CStr(reste)
    chiffreentrer = chiffreentrer \ 8

    chiffreocto = reste & chiffreocto
Loop
MsgBox "Le chiffre en octo est de : " & chiffreocto, , "Conversion Decimal a Octo"
End Sub
```

--

```
Public Function Division(Nombre As Integer)


      i = 1
     j = 1
            Bla = ""
         Nbinit = Nombre
         reste = 0
 ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = Nombre
           ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2) = "÷2"
          ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight

     Do


reste = (Nombre - 2 * Int(Nombre / 2))

Nombre = Int(Nombre / 2)

Bla = reste & Bla


i = i + 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = Nombre
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2) = reste

Loop While (Nombre > 0)

         MsgBox "Le nombre " & Nbinit & " est équivalent à " & Bla & " en binaire"
```

End Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Conversion_Click()
Dim chiffreentrer As Integer
Dim reste As Integer
Dim reste2 As String
Dim chiffreocto As String

chiffreentrer = CInt(InputBox("Entrez un chiffre decimal:", "Conversion    Decimal a Octo"))
Do While chiffreentrer >= 1 Or chiffreentrer <= -1
    reste = chiffreentrer Mod 8
    reste2 = CStr(reste)
    chiffreentrer = chiffreentrer \ 8
    If Left(chiffreocto, 1) = "-" Then chiffreocto = Mid(chiffreocto, 2)
    chiffreocto = reste & chiffreocto
Loop
MsgBox "Le chiffre en octo est de : " & chiffreocto, , "Conversion Decimal a Octo"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I've got another question though, does that code also apply to decimal to binary conversions? I've edited the question to also show the decimal to binary code, what can I do so that also converts negatives too?

Comment: That is a new question.  Please post it as a new question when you can instead of amending this one after getting a correct answer.  I am heading into a meeting and you will get a quicker response from others.